# MariaDB: read in txt file for sql statement

Tags: mariadb, txt

I have a local MariaDB and would like to build the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * from db.id_match WHERE id IN ('C:\CUSIPs.txt')
```

The text file represents a number of IDs (each one written in a separate line - not separated by a ',' or similar).

Is there a way to read in these IDs without having to manually copy each one into the IN-clause and separate them with ' and , ?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: you need to import the File with LOAD local INfile

Comment: thanks- I tried, but the file cannot be found (even though I put it under 'C:\'. Is there a specific place on my pc I need to put it?

Comment: this usually means you don't have the rights to open it, bettter would be to make the file in `c:\myfiles\CUSIPs.txt` Microsoft is very picky who is allowed to access c;

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [CONNECT Engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-csv-and-fmt-table-types/) table that represents the file and then use that table.

Install the connect engine:

```
plugin-load-add=ha_connect.so
```

Create table:

```
create table ips (
ip int not null)
engine=CONNECT table_type=CSV file_name='C:\CUSIPs.txt'
```

And select:

```
SELECT * from db.id_match
JOIN ips ON id=ips.ip
```

Comment: thank you! I am creating the table but the file cannot be found. I am trying to figure out, if there is a specific way to write the file path

Comment: Try a double \\ in case there's SQL escaping at play here. Could use filemon to see what MariaDB is opening or attempting to open during the `select`